# i passing the session from php tags and then try to hide and show the div on page load based on if statement using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I passing the user role from PHP `$session['role']` tags and then try to hide and show the div on page load event based on `if(!sessionRole=='admin')` statement using jQuery.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script type="text/ecmascript"> //script to hide show page on page load.
$(document).ready(function{
  var sessionRole=<?php echo $session_ROLE ?>
  if(!sessionRole=='admin'){
    $('#admin_tool').hide();
  }
});
</script>


<div class="col-md-4" > 
  <div class="widgets" style="margin-top: 15px;">

    <div class='Recent'id='admin_tool' > // dive that i want to hide and show 
      <h4>Tools</h4>
      <hr>
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col'><button type='button' id="btn" class='btn btn-success btn-lg' style='min-width: 150px;'>Publish</button></div>
          <div class='col'><button type='button' id="btn2" class='btn btn-warning btn-lg'style='min-width: 150px;' >Oppose</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row' style='margin-top: 10px;'>
          <div class='col'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' style='min-width: 150px;'>Unpublish</button></div>
          <div class='col'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg' style='min-width: 150px;'>Delete</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Okay, so what is the question? Are you aware that this is completely insecure, and anyone, admin or not, can still view the source for the hidden div?

Comment: Hint: you’re probably not quoting your string correctly. You *would* use `json_encode()` in the PHP to address that issue, but I sincerely hope you choose to secure the site properly instead, not just do a client-side toggle of a div.

Comment: I am trying to hide div content from the other users so that only admin can access and perform an action on the post like delete, unpublish, publish and oppose.

and I am not sure whether it is a secure method or not, so please help me out.

Comment: I understood that part. I’m telling you that it definitely ***is not*** secure. Hiding that div does nothing to keep non-admin users out of sensitive areas of the site. If anything, it makes it *easier* for malevolent actors because the sensitive URLs will be right there in the HTML. Authorization and authentication must both be done server-side, not client-side.

Comment: thank you so much @EdCottrell for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't!

If you want to securely hide something to a type of user, do it from the server.

Wrap the HTML lines for admin in a `if` condition.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-4" > 
  <div class="widgets" style="margin-top: 15px;">

  <?php
  if($session_ROLE == "admin"){
  ?>

    <div class='Recent'id='admin_tool' > // dive that i want to hide and show 
      <h4>Tools</h4>
      <hr>
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col'><button type='button' id="btn" class='btn btn-success btn-lg' style='min-width: 150px;'>Publish</button></div>
          <div class='col'><button type='button' id="btn2" class='btn btn-warning btn-lg'style='min-width: 150px;' >Oppose</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row' style='margin-top: 10px;'>
          <div class='col'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' style='min-width: 150px;'>Unpublish</button></div>
          <div class='col'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg' style='min-width: 150px;'>Delete</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <?php }  // End if admin
  ?>

  </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help, code working perfectly

Comment: By the way, you just missed some quotes around the value echoed: `var sessionRole="<?php echo $session_ROLE ?>";` It is insecure for what you want to do... But passing PHP values to JS often is cool. Just be sure you are not opening a breach with the value passed!